# Last days of previous month

Tags: php, calendar, date

In PHP, I'm generating a calendar with code from [here](http://davidwalsh.name/php-calendar). I've connected it with Basecamp and am successfully calculating the hours worked each day and sum them for the week and month. To properly calculate overtime, I need the hours from the whole week, even when it spans the end/beginning of a month.

[image]

After several hours of trying, I haven't been able to calculate the dates of the days marked with '?' in the above image.

I can't escape the feeling that I'm missing something obvious here, but haven't been able to figure it out. Any help much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mktime()` and set a day argument which is less than `1`: `0` for the last day, `-1` for the day before the last day, etc.

That gives you a UNIX timestamp you can use to find out the weekday and then - until you've reached Sunday/Monday (whatever week start you use) - subtract -86400 or call `mktime()` again with the day reduced by 1.

**Example:**

```
mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, -1, 2010); # timestamp of Nov 29th 00:00:00 2010
```